# Access data in a Set in Java without using an Iterator

Tags: java, set, jdk1.4

I have a stripped down version of Java 1.4.2 that does not have the Iterator class. I am trying to port the T2Framework source to be able to run on this target, however, I have run into the following line of code:

```
for (Class D : domainMap.keySet())
```

where domainMap is of the type java.util.HashMap. For every other Iterator in this source I've encountered so far, I have been able to just use a for loop with an index to resolve the issue of not being able to use an Iterator, however, a Set in Java does not allow you to reference its data by index. Is there another way to access the data in a Set?

Comment: You don't have the `Iterable` class, `Iterator` is there since v1.2

Comment: I know, but this is a stripped down version of Java. There are some classes that are just completely left out (like Iterator), and sometimes methods that were removed as well (e.g. String.split()).

Comment: Also Iterable is not there either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`toArray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29) it, and then use a for loop over that array:

```
Object[] array = domainMap.keySet().toArray();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Object o = domainMap.get(array[i]);

    // Body of loop here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you don't have is the "enhanced for loop" that uses `Iterable`, `Iterator` is in Java since v1.2

You can replace every occurrence of

```
for( Object o : collection ) { 
}
```

With

```
for( Iterator i = collection.iterator(); i.hasNext() ; ) {
   Object o = i.next(); 
}
```

The former is just syntactic sugar of the later ( see the compiled code ).

See:

```
C:\>more > A.java
class A {
   void m() {
      for( Object o : new java.util.HashSet() ) {
      }
   }
}
^C
C:\>javac A.java

C:\>more > B.java
class B {
   void m() {
      for( java.util.Iterator i = new java.util.HashSet().iterator() ; i.hasNext() ; ) {
         Object o = i.next();
      }
   }
}
^C
C:\>javac B.java

C:\>gvim -d a.d b.d
```

[image: diff]

The same!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest either:

a) Creating your own java.util.Iterator class and putting it in the java.util package.

OR

b) Using the Set.toArray() function to your advantage.

Once you've converted the set to an array, it's trivial to iterate through it.

(I'd go with b if this is the only difficulty, a if there are more than one instances of this issue)

Example Set.toArray():

```
Object[] myArray = myMap.keySet().toArray();
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    doStuff((Class)myArray[i]);
```

How to make your own java.util.Iterator:

Use the code from [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Iterator.java.html) and add that class into your classpath.

Comment: a) isn't an option, any changes we make to the runtime will not make it into production per our client.

Comment: b) Oops, must have overlooked that when reading the 1.4 docs, spent too much time coding today haha

Comment: @MetalSearGolid You won't be changing the runtime. As long as the Iterator class is still referenced, but ends up leading to a crash, you'll be able to replace the missing class by adding one to the default class loader.

Comment: I thought about that, but it seemed like a more complex solution than what it needed to be. I should have seen toArray though when I looked at the javadocs though, that was my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the Enumeration, it was like Iterators in pre-generic days. An elements() method on the Set may return it

Comment: i was about to suggest the same thing, but after verification, the Set interface does not have an elements() method.  This method is only provided on hashtable and vector

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand... Iterator is there since java 1.2.

1) your example shows the new syntax of for loop... will not work in 1.4.2
2) I`m sure you can do

```
Iterator it = mySet().iterator();
```

and loop thru it like other respond.

**edit:** ok just saw your new comment up... So you really dont have iterator!!! well... the toArray is in fact the best way to do it